# having trouble making a brute force program that finds out if a number is equal to itself in reverse

Tags: python

basically the title, I have a program that I'm trying to write to see if 2 3-digit number multiplied by each other equal a palindromic number, the problem I am having with the code is that when I run it it doesn't display anything whatsoever

```
def Rev(Number):    
    Reverse = 0    
    while(Number > 0):    
        Reminder = Number %10    
        Reverse = (Reverse *10) + Reminder    
        Number = Number //10    


num1 = 100
num2 = 100
mult = 0
reverse = Rev(mult)

x = 0

while x < 1:
    while num1 < 1000:
        while num2 < 1000:
            mult = num1 * num2
            reverse = Rev(mult)
            if reverse == mult:
                print(mult)
            num2 = num2 + 1
        num1 = num1 + 1
    x = x + 1
```

I also tried adding a print(Reverse) to the end of the Rev function so it displays the output after, but it gives a bunch of zeros and other random numbers

I'm still a beginner in python so I may just be dumb but I appreciate any help given

Comment: What is the `x` variable supposed to be doing?

Comment: `Rev()` doesn't return anything, so there's no point in comparing `reverse` to anything.

Comment: its supposed to end the loop once its finished, though now that im looking  at it it does seem kinda useless

Comment: why isnt Rev() returning anything? am i supposed to have a return at the end of the function?

Comment: can use `break` to end the loop. Or I think the function `Rev(Number)` is missing `return` so not returning any value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of issues. The first is that `Rev` doesn't return a value (so by default it returns `None`), and so `reverse` will never be equal to a number. The second is that you need to re-initialise `num2` for every `num1` loop. Finally the `x` variable is not doing anything, so you can just remove the outer while loop. This code does what you want:

```py
def Rev(Number):    
    Reverse = 0    
    while(Number > 0):    
        Reminder = Number %10    
        Reverse = (Reverse *10) + Reminder    
        Number = Number //10  
    return Reverse

num1 = 100

while num1 < 1000:
    num2 = 100
    while num2 < 1000:
        mult = num1 * num2
        reverse = Rev(mult)
        if reverse == mult:
            print(mult)
        num2 = num2 + 1
    num1 = num1 + 1
```

Output:

```
10201
11211
12221
13231
14241
15251
...
282282
119911
906609
514415
580085
```

Note you may want to store results into a list/dictionary to make it easier to display them in a prettier format.

Comment: i appreciate the help, im still kinda new to functions and didnt know i had to use the return in order for it to work

Comment: @Kadenbarnes no worries - I'm glad this was helpful